# Odd or Even for Fourier Series?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have the function $f(x) = -x^2 + x\pi$ and $0\le x\le \pi$ and without seeing the graph I want to show if it is odd or even, but of course $f(x) = f(-x)$ doesn't show that it is even because I can't take $-x$. So how can I show that it's even?

Comment: You want to show that *what* is even or odd? The Fourier sine series? Cosine series? Full Fourier series? Because the function you have given is neither even nor odd (with respect to $x=0$).

Comment: The concept of odd/even function requires the domain of the function to be symmetric (i.e., $\forall x\in \text{dom}(f)(-x\in \text{dom}(f))$). It doesn't make sense to ask whether a function is even or odd if its domain isn't symmetric. What's being asked of you is to look at the $\pi$-periodic extension of $f$ to $\mathbb R$. A partial reiteration of the present comment can be read [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481485/how-to-know-if-the-function-is-even-or-odd-with-given-domain-codomain-and-relat).

Comment: Even with respect to what?  Reflection across $x=\pi/2$?  You need to check whether $f(x)=f(\pi - x)$ (even) or $f(x)=-f(\pi - x)$ (odd), or neither.

Comment: @mjqxxxx
I have no idea to respect to what , the professor just said that identifying whether a function is odd or even will simplify the process of computing the fourier series.
so my answer would be to check if $f(x)=f(\pi-x)$ because of my x can only be between 0 and pi ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd do.  Since $f(\pi - x)=-(\pi - x)^2 + (\pi - x)\pi = \pi x - x^2 = f(x)$, the function is even with respect to $x=\pi/2$, and so you only need terms with that symmetry (i.e., the $\sin$ terms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not well-formed, but I will take a shot in an effort to help form it.

The answer depends on how you extend $f(x)=-x^2+\pi x$, $0< x< \pi$ to $-\pi< x< 0$. If you do an *even* extension, $$f_e(x):=\begin{cases}f(-x), &-\pi<x<0,\\ f(x), &0<x<\pi,\end{cases}$$ then the full Fourier series will end up being just a Fourier cosine series (all sine terms vanish) and thus the resulting Fourier series is even. On the other hand, if you do an *odd* extension, $$f_o(x):=\begin{cases}-f(-x), &-\pi<x<0,\\ f(x), &0<x<\pi,\end{cases}$$ then the full Fourier series will end up being just a Fourier sine series (all cosine terms vanish) and thus the resulting Fourier series is odd. Finally, you could extend $f$ in some arbitrary way and the result be neither even nor odd.

---

The only other thing I can think that you might be asking is, *if I just use $f(x)$ as defined on $0<x<\pi$, will its Fourier series end up being even or odd?*

The answer there is (again), it depends on whether you use a Fourier sine or cosine series. If you do a Fourier cosine series for $f$ on $0<x<\pi$, the series will be even (and it will correspond to the even periodic extension of $f$), but if you do a Fourier sines series, the series will be odd (and the series will correspond to the odd periodic extension of $f$).